# How many bytes does a #define string (string literal) take?

Tags: c++, c, variables

```
#define STR "test1"
```

Why does this take 6 bytes?

sizeof(STR) = 6

Comment: Do you ever invoke the `STR` macro in your code?  If not, then this takes no bytes...

Answer (score 17, accepted):

There is a trailing `'\0'` at the end.

Answer (score 5):

It has nothing to do with `#define`.  A character array would be the same size:

```
const char str[] = { "test1" };
sizeof (str) == 6
```

The reason this string is 6 bytes long is that strings in C have a terminating NUL character to mark the end.

Comment: That's not an array, it's a pointer to a string literal, and `sizeof(str)` will return the size of the pointer type for your machine.

Comment: What this meant to say is that `const char str[] = "test1";` is the same as `const char str[] = {'t','e','s','t','1','\0'};`

Comment: Umm, yeah.  I feel really horrible, especially since I thought about the difference between sizeof array and sizeof pointer before typing the answer, and then my fingers hit the wrong keys anyways.

Answer (score 5):

a `#define` just does a text replacement before compiling.

```
#define STR "test1"
sizeof(STR);
```

is actually seen by the compiler as

```
sizeof("test1");
```

now why is that 6 and not 5?  because there's a null terminator at the end of the string.

Answer (score 2):

Strings in C are arrays of `char`s, with a null terminator i.e. they end with the `\0`. The common alternative is Pascal-style strings, where the string stores the array of `char`s without the null terminator, and stores the length of the string somewhere instead.

Comment: Speaking of Pascal strings in the context of C and C++ and string literals, is terribly misleading.

Answer (score 1):

What the others said ... **BUT**

In `C`, preprocessing tokens take no space. It depends on how you use them

```
#define STR "test1"

char x[] = STR;         /* 6 bytes */
char *y = STR;          /* sizeof (char*) bytes (plus possibly 6 bytes) */
int ch = STR[3];        /* 1 byte (or sizeof (int), depending on how you look at it) */
if (ch == STR[1])       /* 1 byte (or sizeof (int) or no bytes or ...) */

printf("==>" STR "<==") /* 5 bytes ??? */
```

Answer (score 1):

> Why does this take 6 bytes?

Actually, it will take (6 bytes × the number of times you use it), because it's a preprocessor macro.

Try `const char *STR = "test1"` instead.

Comment: It's unspecified whether identical string literals are distinct objects. I.e. the value of the expression `"test1" == "test1"` could be true or false. This can even depend on compiler settings.

Answer (score 0):

The latest C compiler has a feature to guess if the person writing the program is in a learning phase and give answers which make them search wider and deeper, and thus enrich their knowledge.

After programming for some time, depending of your learning, you might see the value go down to 5. ;-)

JK.. as someone else said, it symbolically nothing at the end which ironically takes a byte.